# Detect whether a type is a vector of enum

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

I get an error:

> error: default template arguments may not be used in partial specializations

in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

enum class MyEnum
{
    aaa,
    bbb,
};

template<class T>
struct is_vector_enum
{
    using type = T ;
    constexpr static bool value = false;
};

template<class T, class std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>  // Error ....
struct is_vector_enum<std::vector<T>>
{
    using type = std::vector<T> ;
    constexpr static bool value = true;
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << "is_vector_enum: " << is_vector_enum<std::vector<MyEnum>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The purpose is to detect whether a type is a vector of enum.

How should I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specializations are allowed to have a different number of template parameters than the primary.  In fact, this happens quite often.  However, as the error indicates, you are not allowed to give any of them default arguments.

That aside, I prefer simplicity, when possible.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct is_vector_enum : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_vector_enum<std::vector<T>> : std::is_enum<T> { };
```

Answer (score 4):

Your primary template and your specialization need to have the same number of template parameters. At the moment, your primary has 1:

```
template<class T>
struct is_vector_enum
```

and your specialization has 2:

```
template<class T, class std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
struct is_vector_enum<std::vector<T>>
```

The typical way to do this in C++17 is to provide a dummy 2nd template parameter to the primary, that defaults to `void`, to then let you do the SFINAE in the second parameter:

```
template <class T, class Enable=void>
struct is_vector_enum { /* ... */ };

template <class T>
struct is_vector_enum<std::vector<T>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>>> { /* ... */ };
```

---

A different way entirely to do this would be:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, int> = 0>
std::true_type impl(std::vector<T> const&);

template <typename T>
std::false_type impl(T const&);

template <typename U>
using is_vector_enum = decltype(impl(std::declval<T>()));
```

Note that the `impl` functions here are not defined, and are not intended to be invoked.

Comment: What's the use of enable_if in the template specialization? Can't the specialization just use the `value = std::is_enum<T>::value;` inside it?

Comment: @Samik Yes (or just inherit from `std::is_enum` as Jody Hagins' answer suggests). But maybe you're going to do something else in the specialization such that you need the constraint up front?